# Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to FB graph API and I try to include the FB login in my website, I following the official FB login tutorial from their website, But after login I get the following error:

```
Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/fbsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'xxx',
'app_secret' => 'xxx',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
// . . .
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['public_profile', 'email']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://-myserver-/login-callback.php',    $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

login-callback.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/fbsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'xxx',
'app_secret' => 'xxx',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
// . . .
]);



$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
// Logged in!
$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// Now you can redirect to another page and use the
 // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
}
?>
```

example-canvas-app.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/fbsdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'xxx',
'app_secret' => 'xxx',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
// . . .
]);



$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
try {
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
// Logged in.
}
?>
```

I already searched in stack and google but I can't find any solution

Comment: This is very very likely to be a configuration issue with your server or network, are you sure both your IPV4 and IPV6 connections allow your machine to contact graph.facebook.com?

Comment: Which type of server I need for using Facebook API ?, I am currently using a free server from Hostinger

Comment: Any server which can run the programming language you're building your site with, and which has network connectivity to Facebook's API servers

Comment: I am using hostinger to try facebook login @salihkallai , so does hostinger have connectivity to facebook api?

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Sadly no! I continued with Google login.

Comment: same issue in my locahost..anyidea how to solve ?

Answer (score 5):

Hostinger's free server does not allow a connection to Fb's SDK as mentioned by their customer service.